# Why won't GlassFish start?

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4

I am trying to start GlassFish 4, but I get these error messages:

```
Bad Network Configuration.  DNS can not resolve the hostname: 
java.net.UnknownHostException: duboiss-mini-2: duboiss-mini-2: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the hostname of the computer to something else, then closed and reopened the terminal window. That fixed it. I don't know why, though...